# MARS Mips Breakpoint

Tags: mips, breakpoints, mars-simulator

I want to check out what the registers are at this point in my program (as pictured). Naturally, I tried to add a breakpoint in my MARS mips compiler as pictured below. However, MARS just blows through it without stopping. So, I tried to get my program to crash right after this but I couldn't get it to crash, even by setting the stack point to -4 and calling lw. Any ideas as to how to get it to stop at a given line?  [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After one compiles, one cannot exit the "execute" window or else any breakpoints will not work (or at least this is what my experience was). Idk if anyone else can corroborate this?

Comment: Yes, it appears the breakpoints disappear if you change windows. So assemble before setting breakpoints and just stay on the execute window